# When to use positive and negative $\rm g$ when calculating force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, string

My teacher gave us a question the other day:

> A $20\  \rm kg$ sign is supposed to hang from a pair of wires attached to the wall and support beam as shown in the diagram. The worded that will be used can withstand a force of tension up to $\rm 300\ N$ each. Determine the tension in wire one $F_{T_1}$ and wire two $F_{T_2}$
>
> Diagram :
>
> [image]

In the explanation, he used negative $g$ to calculate the gravitational force on the first wire. I asked why since the gravity is pulling the sign down (therefore should be positive) and he explained that force and gravitational acceleration are different, and I just can’t grasp why. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Are you familiar with vectors and free-body diagrams?

Comment: *The worded that will be used can withstand a force of tension up to 300 N each.* That doesn't make sense. Is there a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point:  in any problem involving forces, the first step is to chose a system of coordinate axes, and the which directions will be considered positive and which negative.  This is necessary for the next step:  separating each force into its x-component and y-component.

Secondly, you need to pick a point and calculate the components of all the forces acting on this point.

In this case, the most convenient definition would be to have the horizontal direction be the x-axis, with forces along this axis to the right taken as positive.  The vertical direction is then along the y-axis, with forces upward being taken as positive.

Further, angles are measured counter-clockwise from the positive x-axis.

Other definitions are just as legitimate.  These happen to make the signs for all the trig ratios match the choices for positive and negative directions

Finally, the point where the three cables meet is a good choice for the point to be calculated.  Since this point is has constant zero velocity, its acceleration is zero.  ***The sum of all the forces acting on this point must be zero***.

Consider first the horizontal forces acting on this connection.

The cable from the load exerts a downward force on the connection;  there is no horizontal component from this force.

Cable #1 exerts a horizontal force of $F_{T1} \times \cos(40 ^0)$ to the right on the junction point.  Note that it is not necessary to apply a positive sign;  the cosine function takes care of this.

Cable #2 exerts a horizontal force of $F_{T2} \times \cos(180 ^0) = -F_{T2}$ to the right on the junction point.  Again, there is no need to apply any sign;  the cosine of $180 ^0$ is already $(-1)$

Since the point is not accelerating in the horizontal direction, we have as our first equation:$$F_{T1} \times \cos(40 ^0)+(-F_{T2})=0$$

Consider now the vertical forces acting on the junction point.

$F_{T2}$ acts horizontally;  it has no vertical component.

The short cable from the box must hold up the box;  the tension in that cable is $mg = 20g$.  So this cable exerts an upward force on the junction point of $20g \times \sin 270^0 = -20g$.  Note again that the choice of down-negative is built into the choice of angles.

Cable #1 exerts an upward force on the junction point of $F_{T1} \sin(40^0)$.  Since the point is not accelerating vertically, all the vertical forces must add to zero. We have a our second equation:$$(-20g)+F_{T1} \sin(40^0)=0$$With a value for $g$ and the value of some trig functions, we can solve these two equations.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution :

Since the wire T1 is connected to the support beam , the tension on the rope is opposite to the force applied by gravity which is downwards , hence taking the direction of the tension as positive , the gravity 's direction is negative. But if you want to take the direction of gravity as positive , the tension is negative ( its an arbitrary choice ). If u have knowledge of free body diagrams or vectors , you would understand it better like @g stated .

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the error but this doesn't change the answer much , hope you get more clarity now

Answer (score 0):

It is merely a matter of convention. Force and acceleration are different, but in general, the direction of acceleration is the same as the direction of net force. A good way to assign directions correctly is to remember that if the force is acting opposite to the direction of motion, the velocity and acceleration will be opposite in sign.